# Show Error in Scanline When PixelFormat is pf8bit

Tags: delphi

I use [this code](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs?view=entry&id=3342) to scan very fast Bitmap.

Everything is Ok When PixelFormat = pf24bit but my program only work with 256 image color and for this reason PixelFormat = pf8bit.

When PixelFormat = pf8bit this code show error.

```
  var
    w, h: Integer;
    CurrRow, OffSet: Integer;
    x: byte;
    pRed, pGreen, pBlue: PByte;
  begin
    CurrRow := Integer(aBitmap.Scanline[0]);
    OffSet := Integer(aBitmap.Scanline[1]) - CurrRow;
    Result:= False;
    for h := 0 to aBitmap.Height - 1 do
    begin
      for w := 0 to aBitmap.Width - 1 do
      begin
        pBlue := PByte(CurrRow + w * 3);
        pGreen := PByte(CurrRow + w * 3 + 1);
        pRed := PByte(CurrRow + w * 3 + 2);
      end;
      inc(CurrRow, OffSet);
    end;
```

now I use this code to swap color but dont work because scanline dont check color

```
  procedure ReplaceColor(aBitmap: TBitmap; swap1, swap2: TRGBQuad);
  var
  w, h, k: Integer;
  pScanline: pByte;
  Red, Green, Blue, palindex: Byte;
  PalEntries: array[0..255] of TRGBQuad;
begin
  if aBitmap.Palette <> 0 then
    GetPaletteEntries(aBitmap.Palette, 0, 255, PalEntries);

  for h := 0 to aBitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    pScanline := pByte(aBitmap.Scanline[h]);

    for w := 0 to aBitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin

           Blue:=  PalEntries[pScanline^].rgbBlue ;
           Red:=  PalEntries[pScanline^].rgbRed ;
           Green:=  PalEntries[pScanline^].rgbGreen ;

          if (Blue = swap1.rgbBlue) and (Red = swap1.rgbRed) and
            (Green = swap1.rgbGreen) then
          begin
            Blue := swap2.rgbBlue;

            Green := swap2.rgbGreen;

            Red := swap2.rgbRed;

          end
          else if (Blue = swap2.rgbBlue) and (Red = swap2.rgbRed) and
            (Green = swap2.rgbGreen) then
          begin
            Blue := swap1.rgbBlue;

            Green := swap1.rgbGreen;

            Red := swap1.rgbRed;

          end;

         Inc(pScanline);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: *this code show error* is not a problem description that is useful. What **error** does it **show**? How does it **show** an error? Is it a compiler error? A runtime error? Does it produce the wrong output? You've not explained a problem or asked a meaningful question. You know exactly what *error* you're getting, because it's happening in your code on your computer. We can't see the error from where we're sitting, so if you want help you need to explain it to us clearly.

Comment: Access Memory Error

Comment: As I said in my answer, 8bit bitmaps DO NOT store colors in the scanline pixels, they are stored in a separate color palette, the pixels are indexes into that palette. If you want to swap colors, you have to modify the color table, or change the index values.

Comment: For failing to describe what the error is -1

Comment: ok @RemyLebeau , thanks

Answer (score 5):

The code fails for `pf8bit` because it is not written to handle `pf8bit`.  It is written to handle `pf24bit` instead.

The code is expecting each scanline to consist of `width` number of 3-byte (24 bits) pixels containing the actual RGB values.  But in `pf8bit`, each scanline contains 1-byte (8 bit) pixels which are indexes into the bitmap's color palette.  You are not accounting for that at all.

Try something more like this instead:

```
var
  w, h: Integer;
  pScanline: PByte;
  Red, Green, Blue: Byte;
  PalEntries: array[0..255] of TRGBQuad;
begin
  Result := False;

  if aBitmap.Palette <> 0 then
    GetPaletteEntries(aBitmap.Palette, 0, 255, PalEntries);

  for h := 0 to aBitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    pScanline := PByte(aBitmap.Scanline[h]);
    for w := 0 to aBitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      case aBitmap.PixelFormat of
        pf8Bit: begin
          Blue := PalEntries[pScanline^].rgbBlue;
          Green := PalEntries[pScanline^].rgbGreen;
          Red := PalEntries[pScanline^].rgbRed;
          Inc(pScanline);
        end;
        pf24Bit: begin
          Blue := PRGBTriple(pScanline).rgbtBlue;
          Green := PRGBTriple(pScanline).rgbtGreen;
          Red := PRGBTriple(pScanline).rgbtRed;
          Inc(pScanline, SizeOf(TRGBTriple));
        end;
        // etc for other color depths...
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

You need to do some research on how bitmaps actually work, particularly in relation to the format of the scanlines at the various color depths.

[Bitmaps overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183377.aspx)

Comment: @AliReza: In what way exactly? Please be more specific.